# installing ruby-1.8.4 with rails 2.3.2 giving me error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a ruby on rails application, requirement for that app is as below.

1. ruby version must be ruby-1.8.4
2. rails 2.3.2

I have installed ruby-1.8.4 without rvm, and installed rubygems version "gem -v"( 1.3.1 ).

But the problem is that when i trying to run command

> sudo gem install rails -v=2.3.2

it give me error like this

ERROR:  Error installing rails:
rake requires Ruby version >= 1.8.6

Please suggest me how i can install rails 2.3.2 with ruby version 1.8.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beware, running such an antique version of ruby/rails has security and other implications.  Ruby 1.8.4 is 7 years old, and Rails 2.3.2 is 3 and a half.

But anyway, you need to specifically install an older version of rake before trying to install rails; otherwise gem will just try to install the latest version of rake.

```
gem install rake -v=0.8.7
gem install rails -v=2.3.2
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in `rails`, it's in `rake` gem. Downgrade `rake` gem to earlier version - minimum required for rails 2.3.2.